# Is it possible to use MEL to do a dynamic variable name or something else?

Tags: mule

I have a variable name="a#[ticket]" value="0"

The name will be a123456789 and the value will be 0

But how to access this value if i just print the a#[ticket] i will have a123456789 and what i need is #[a123456789] so it will give me 0.

The code so far:

```
<set-session-variable variableName="ticketId" value="a#[message.inboundProperties['ticket']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-session-variable variableName="#[ticketId]" value="0" doc:name="Variable"/>

<logger message="#[#[ticketId]]" level="INFO" doc:name="messageID2"/>
```

and that last line will fail, but i dont know how to call that dynamic variable...

->mule version 3.4

Comment: For future readers of this question and the accepted answer, if you want a non-Groovy MEL-only solution, my answer below is tested working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a dynamic variable name and use it with expression or logger you need to do as follow:

```
<set-session-variable variableName="a#[message.inboundProperties['ticket']]" value="0" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

That will set a dynamic name for a variable based on a ticket sent in the INBOUND message

Them i ve used a script to place it inside msgId:

```
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
            def String ticket = 'a' + message.getProperty('ticket', org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INBOUND);
            return ["msgId":this[ticket]]
        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
```

And that way i can access the variable value:

```
<logger message="#[msgId]" level="INFO" doc:name="variableValue"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand how `return ["msgId":this[ticket]]` in the Groovy component can set a flow var. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I dont know i have tested and it works perfect it will print whatever value ive place on variable named `a#[message.inboundProperties['ticket']]`

Comment: But doesn't the Groovy component change the current message payload to a Map containing `"msgId":this[ticket]`? Also why `this[ticket]`? Why not just `ticket` to refer to the variable you just created with `def String ticket`? There's too much magic/mystery at play here...

Comment: In a paper i was reading about mule its a way to send the content of a variable to another variable! Inside ticket i will have the name a123456789, and the variable with that name have the value 0 that i declared before, so i will have msgId with the value of a123456789 and it will be usable on an expression and on log, so this[ticket] will actually give back the value stored on a123456789, the variable i just declared and it worked :)

Comment: OK, I see. The Groovy component binds session variables to the context, so `this[ticket]` is equivalent to `message.getProperty(ticket, org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.SESSION)`. See here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.0/modules/scripting/src/main/java/org/mule/module/scripting/component/Scriptable.java#L257

Comment: For future readers of this question and answer, if you want a non-Groovy MEL-only solution, my answer below is tested working.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following:

```
<expression-component>t=message.inboundProperties['ticket'];flowVars['a'+t]='0'</expression-component>
```

to set a flow-var named from the concatenation of "a" and the value of the "ticket" inbound property.

To read it, use:

```
#[t=message.inboundProperties['ticket'];flowVars['a'+t]]
```

Note that if you copy the `ticket` inbound property in a flowVar with:

```
<set-variable variableName="ticket" value="#[message.inboundProperties['ticket']]" />
```

Then the syntax for assigning simply becomes:

```
<expression-component>flowVars['a'+ticket]='0'</expression-component>
```

and for reading:

```
#[flowVars['a'+ticket]]
```

Comment: Well, i got an error with that expression:
Execution of the expression "flowVars['a'+message.inboundProperties['ticket']]='0'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Any idea?

Comment: and if i do this:
`<set-variable variableName="a#[message.inboundProperties['ticket']]" value="0" doc:name="Variable"/>
  
<logger message="#[flowVars['a'+message.inboundProperties['ticket']]" level="INFO" doc:name="messageID2"/>`
i only get the string: `#[flowVars['a'+message.inboundProperties['ticket']]` as a result but not 0 like it was set...

Comment: I doubt you can use a MEL expression in `set-variable`'s `variableName`. That's why I suggested you do it with code. Are you sure `message.inboundProperties['ticket']` contains something? Also for the above exception, instead of sharing a tiny bit of it in a comment like this, pastebin it **in full** and share the link.

Comment: yeah, ive printed with #[flovars]  even can set the variable using MEL, but could not compare or use its value, them ive made a way i will post here my solution in a minute. :)

Comment: I have fixed my answer and made suggestion to simplify the syntax.